# Computing and undestanding scale-free networks using Barabási-Albert model

Tags: c++, r, graph, igraph

I'm trying to implement an algorithm for generating graphs following [Barabási-Albert (BA) model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barab%C3%A1si%E2%80%93Albert_model). Under this model, the degree distribution follows a power-law:

P(k) ~ k^-λ

Where the exponent λ should equal 3.

For simplicity, I will focus here on the R code, where I'm using `igraph` functions. However I get networks with λ != 3. It seems that this has been a topic extensively covered ([example question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47922737/barabasi-albert-model-wrong-degree-exponent), [eq2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43769677/input-to-fit-a-power-law-to-degree-distribution-of-a-network), [eq3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10622401/implementing-barabasi-albert-method-for-creating-scale-free-networks)), but I haven't been able to find a satisfactory solution.

In R I use `igraph:::sample_pa` function to generate a graph following the BA model. In the reproducible example below, I set

```
# Initialize
set.seed(1234)
order = 100
v_degrees = vector()

for (i in 1:10000) {
  g <- sample_pa(order, power=3, m=8)

  # Get degree distribution
  d = degree(g, mode="all")
  dd = degree_distribution(g, mode="all", cumulative=FALSE)

  d = 1:max(d)
  probability = dd[-1]
  nonzero.position = which(probability !=0)
  probability = probability[nonzero.position]
  d = d[nonzero.position]

  # Fit power law distribution and get gamma exponent
  reg = lm (log(probability) ~ log(d))
  cozf = coef(reg)
  power.law.fit = function(x) exp(cozf[[1]] + cozf[[2]] * log(x))
  gamma = -cozf[[2]]
  v_degrees[i] = gamma
}
```

The graph seems to be scale free in fact, giving *gamma=0.72±0.21* with order 100 and *gamma=0.68±0.24* for order 10,000, and similar results varying the parameter *m*. But the exponent is clearly different from the expected gamma=3.

In fact I was trying to implement this model on a different language (C++, see code below), but I get similar results with exponents lower than 3. So I wonder if this is a common misunderstanding on the BA model or there's something wrong in the previous calculations fitting the power law distribution, of it contrarily to what is commonly expected this is the normal behavior of the BA model.

In case someone is interested or is more familiarized with C++, see appendix below.

**Appendix: C++ code**
For understanding the code below, assume an object class `Graph`, and a `connect` function that created an edge between two vertices passed as argument. Below I give code of two relevant functions **BA_step** and **build_BA**.

**BA_step**

```
void Graph::BA_step (int ID, int m, std::vector<double>& freqs) {
  std::vector<int> connect_history;
  vertices.push_back(ID);

  // Connect node ID to a random node i with pi ~ ki / sum kj
  while (connect_history.size() < m) {
      double U (sample_prob()); // gets a value in the range [0,1)
      int index (freqs[freqs.size()-1]);
      for (int i(0); i<freqs.size(); ++i) {
          if (U<=freqs[i]/index && !is_in(connect_history, i)) { // is_in checks if i exists in connect_history
              connect(ID, i);
              connect_history.push_back(i);
              break;
          }
      }
  }

  // Update vector of absolute edge frequencies
  for (int i(0); i<connect_history.size(); ++i) {
      int index (connect_history[i]);
      for (int j(index); j<freqs.size(); ++j) {
          ++freqs[j];
      }
  }
  freqs.push_back(m+freqs[freqs.size()-1]);
  }
```

**build_BA**

```
void Graph::build_BA (int m0, int m) {

  // Initialization
  std::vector<double> cum_nedges;
  std::vector<int> connect_history;
  for (int ID(0); ID<m0; ++ID) {
      vertices.push_back(ID);
  }

  // Initial BA step
  vertices.push_back(m0);
  for (int i(0); i<m; ++i) {
      connect(m0, i);
      connect_history.push_back(i);
  }
  cum_nedges.push_back(1);
  for (int i(1); i<m; ++i) cum_nedges.push_back(cum_nedges[cum_nedges.size()-1]+1);
  cum_nedges.push_back(m+m);

  // BA model
  for (int ID(m0+1); ID<order; ++ID) {
      BA_step(ID, m, cum_nedges);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things might help:

### `sample_pa` arguments to get exponent `alpha = 3`

Are really `power = 1` and `m = 1` (check definition in that wikipedia article against the igraph::sample_pa documentation---the `power` argument doesn't mean the degree of the power-law distribution).

### Power laws are hard to estimate

Just running OLS/LM on the degree distribution gives you an exponent closer to 0 than 3 (underestimated, in other words). Instead, if you use the `igraph::power_law_fit` command with a high `xmin`, you'll get answers closer to 3. Check [Aaron Clauset's page and publications](http://tuvalu.santafe.edu/~aaronc/powerlaws/) for more info on estimating power laws. Really you need to estimate an optimal x-min for every degree distribution.

Here's some code that'll work a bit better:

```
library(igraph)
set.seed(1234)
order = 10000
v_degrees = vector()
for (i in 1:100) {
  g <- sample_pa(order, power = 1, m = 1)
  d <- degree(g, mode="all")
  v_degrees[i] <- fit_power_law(d, ceiling(mean(d))+100) %>% .$alpha
}
v_degrees %>% summary()
##   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
##  2.646   2.806   2.864   2.873   2.939   3.120
```

Note that I make up the x-min to use (`ceiling(mean(d))+100`). Changing that will change your answers.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I will look into it more carefully tomorrow. However, I must say I'm confused, because playing with small graph orders (say around 10) and `plot(g)` one can see that the `m` argument behaves as expected according to BA. Thus, I still don't understand why changing `m` the mean exponent vary (eg. mean = 1.9 if I repeat the example with m=8).

Comment: All right, it is more clear now. Clauset et al (2009) reference has been key to understand the problem. I'm in debt with you. Thank you!